# Need help understanding a type error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a multiplication tutor program that is assigned to meet the following criteria:

- Program asks the user how man problems they want to solve, if the
  user enters a value more than 10 the program interprets the number as
  an error and prompts the user for a different value.
- Program generates a random multiplication problem with two variable
  numbers between 0 and 12.
- Program prints the problem and prompts the user to answer it, if the
  user does not answer it correctly the program will tell the user if
  his answer was too high or too low and then ask a new question.

I found the following code on this website and thought I could modify it to work in the ways described above:

```
import random
import math

game = int(input("How many problems do you want?\n"))
num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
num_2 = random.randint(1,10)

def main(game):
    random.seed()
    count = 0
    correct = 0
    #wrong != 0 #Took this variable out and replaced it with "if guess != answer" ('wrong' was originally part of an else statement) because it was not working properly.
    while count < game:
        num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
        guess = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "."))
        answer = str(num_1*num_2)
        count += 1

        if guess == answer:
            correct += 1
            print1("Correct!")
        if guess != answer:
            print("Sorry, the answer is", answer, ".")

        if game > 1:
        result = correct * 100./game  
    print("You got ", "%.1f"%result, "of the problems.")

main()
```

**but....** I keep getting the following error and don't know what to do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Internet Fate\Desktop\game.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'game'
```

I have been trying to figure out what the issue is for over an hour now and I am starting to get stressed. In addition to this I have no idea how to get the program to only accept an input from 1-10 for the number of times the game is played (referring to criteria point number one). How to get the program to tell the user that their answer was too high or too low and then have it give them a new problem (referring to point three). And no idea how to repeat this process the designated number of times and then restart.

Comment: It's defined as taking a parameter that it will refer to as `game` and you're not passing it anything. This isn't even a gotcha; you just need to learn the basics. I recommend the excellent [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Comment: I completely agree with you and thank you for replying. I will be sure to check out this tutorial i am watching one on youtube right now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you have more questions after you do so, please provide a more specific title than "I'm new and I need help," as that could apply to most questions and doesn't tell us anything about the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace last `main()` with `main(game)` and make this small changes, remember to read the python tutorials, good luck!

```
import random
import math

game = int(input("How many problems do you want?\n"))
num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
num_2 = random.randint(1,10)

def main(game):
    random.seed()
    count = 0
    correct = 0
    result = 0 #Here we initialized result to 0

    while count < game:
        num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
        guess = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "."))
        answer = num_1*num_2 # Here we don't convert to string so the next "if" works
        count += 1

        if guess == answer:
            correct += 1
            print("Correct!")
        if guess != answer:
            print("Sorry, the answer is", answer, ".")

        if game > 1:
            result = correct * 100./game  
    print("You got ", "%.1f"%result, "of the problems.")

main(game) #send game as parameter
```

Comment: Marking as accepted answer (with the check icon near the answer) is the best way to say thanks in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Ok i have done it! Now I am having another issue :/                          How many problems do you want?
1
What is 6x5.30
Sorry, the answer is 30 .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Internet Fate\Desktop\game.py", line 30, in <module>
    main(game)
  File "C:\Users\Internet Fate\Desktop\game.py", line 28, in main
    print("You got ", "%.1f"%result, "of the problems.")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
>>>

Comment: @noerror - It sounds like you need to learn some more basics from that tutorial (also, try to only ask one question per question, as SO is not intended as a 1-on-1 tutorial service).